# How to track the response from Database Procedure in Mule

Tags: mule, procedure

I have a use case as below:

In my Mule flow , i have database outbound endpoint with Procedure call configuration on Database connecter. I am able to insert the data using the procedure call.
But for the i want to get some data as response when i invoked procedure from Mule.

I am using Oracle XE.

can some one help me out..

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Mule CE JDBC transport for procedure calls uses Apache QueryRunner update method that only returns the number of rows updated, which is then printed out with the logger. You can not get any return data using it, unless you implement a custom sqlStatementStrategyFactory for the JDBC endpoint. See Mule JDBC docs + their GitHub repo for info on implementing the required classes, if you really need it.

Comment: See this file to start learning how this works: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.2/transports/jdbc/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/jdbc/sqlstrategy/DefaultSqlStatementStrategyFactory.java. I am writing a blog post about extending the Mule JDBC, but might take a few days before it's ready.

Comment: Hi Anton ,Thanks for the response. It really helps for my startup on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mule Enterprise Edition the JDBC EE endpoint fully supports calling stored procedures with in and out variables in addition to the result.

The name of the out variable that you name in your Mule call will end up in the endpoint's Map as a key with the same name.

Comment: hi Jake , thanks for the response. Currently the situation is I have procedure call from Mule. My procedure will return list of values for given key search as input. But those values I am not able to capture in Mule Out Variable of Proc call.